# Downloading A MP4 File in Java?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to create a java program that downloads a video off of a specific website by using JSoup. However, I have now realized that JSoup cannot download mp4 files; they are not supported. Currently, I have it so it connects to the website, grabs the IFrame link, which gets the download link that is stored on another website, then gets the direct download link from the server. Now, I can't figure out how to actually download the file. I am still new to Java, so I don't know how to use Https requests or File.IO Utilities to download files that way. I looked up some examples, but none of them seemed to work for me. I also tried using Apache Commons IO, but I couldn't get it to add as a library; whenever I went to "Add Files or Directories" the .Java files would not show up (I also tried the "Select Library Type"), nor would it allow me to drag-and-drop the files. Anyway, I don't know what else to do, so I am posting this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
package com.trentmenard;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;


class ExtractorAndDownloader {
    private String URL;
    private Document currentWebsite;

    ExtractorAndDownloader(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
        getIFrameLink(URL);
    }

    private void getIFrameLink(String URL) {
        System.out.println("Attempting Connection to: " + URL);
        try {
            currentWebsite = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established!");
            Element iFrame = currentWebsite.selectFirst("iframe");
            String iFrameLink = iFrame.attr("src");
            System.out.println("Grabbing IFrame Link: " + iFrameLink);
            getDownloadLink(iFrameLink);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void getDownloadLink(String URL) {
        System.out.println("Attempting Connection to: " + URL);
        try {
            currentWebsite = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established!");
            Element hiddenElementID = currentWebsite.getElementById("id");
            String hiddenElementIDValue = hiddenElementID.attr("value");
            System.out.println("Grabbing Hidden Element ID Value: " + hiddenElementIDValue);
            System.out.println("Grabbing ReDirect Link: " + " https://www.vidstreaming.io/download?id=" + hiddenElementIDValue);
            getReDirectDownloadLink("https://www.vidstreaming.io/download?id=" + hiddenElementIDValue);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void getReDirectDownloadLink(String URL) {
        System.out.println("Attempting Connection to: " + URL);
        try {
            currentWebsite = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established!");
            Element dowloadClassOriginal = currentWebsite.getElementsContainingOwnText("Download (orginalP - mp4)").first();
            String dowloadClassOriginalReDirectLink = dowloadClassOriginal.attr("href");
            System.out.println("Grabbing ReDirect Link: " + dowloadClassOriginalReDirectLink);
            downloadUsingDirectLink(dowloadClassOriginalReDirectLink);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void downloadUsingDirectLink(String URL) {
        System.out.println("Attempting Connection to: " + URL);
        try{
            currentWebsite = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established!");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the error message, saying it's an unsupported file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=61448:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Trent\Desktop\SAOEpisodeDownloader\out\production\SAOEpisodeDownloader;C:\Users\Trent\Downloads\jsoup-1.12.1.jar" com.trentmenard.Main
Attempting Connection to: https://swordartonlineepisode.com/sword-art-online-season-3-episode-1-english-dubbed-watch-online/
Connection Successfully Established!
Grabbing IFrame Link: https://vidstreaming.io/streaming.php?id=MTEzMzQ1
Attempting Connection to: https://vidstreaming.io/streaming.php?id=MTEzMzQ1
Connection Successfully Established!
Grabbing Hidden Element ID Value: MTEzMzQ1
Grabbing ReDirect Link:  https://www.vidstreaming.io/download?id=MTEzMzQ1
Attempting Connection to: https://www.vidstreaming.io/download?id=MTEzMzQ1
Connection Successfully Established!
Grabbing ReDirect Link: https://st1x.cdnfile.info/user1342/1f1b04321e51fac1c1d1c23a1de4f7f0/EP.1.mp4?token=QPVm8x5GnYo6uFYLHqfjwg&expires=1578391941&id=113345&title=(orginalP - mp4) Sword+Art+Online%3A+Alicization+%28Dub%29+Episode+1
Attempting Connection to: https://st1x.cdnfile.info/user1342/1f1b04321e51fac1c1d1c23a1de4f7f0/EP.1.mp4?token=QPVm8x5GnYo6uFYLHqfjwg&expires=1578391941&id=113345&title=(orginalP - mp4) Sword+Art+Online%3A+Alicization+%28Dub%29+Episode+1
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=video/mp4, URL=https://st1x.cdnfile.info/user1342/1f1b04321e51fac1c1d1c23a1de4f7f0/EP.1.mp4?token=QPVm8x5GnYo6uFYLHqfjwg&expires=1578391941&id=113345&title=(orginalP%20-%20mp4)%20Sword+Art+Online%3A+Alicization+%28Dub%29+Episode+1
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:770)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:705)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:295)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:284)
    at com.trentmenard.ExtractorAndDownloader.downloadUsingDirectLink(ExtractorAndDownloader.java:68)
    at com.trentmenard.ExtractorAndDownloader.getReDirectDownloadLink(ExtractorAndDownloader.java:58)
    at com.trentmenard.ExtractorAndDownloader.getDownloadLink(ExtractorAndDownloader.java:43)
    at com.trentmenard.ExtractorAndDownloader.getIFrameLink(ExtractorAndDownloader.java:27)
    at com.trentmenard.ExtractorAndDownloader.<init>(ExtractorAndDownloader.java:16)
    at com.trentmenard.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Connection Failed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
private static void getVideo(String src) throws IOException {

    String folder = null;

    //Exctract the name of the video from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

    if (indexname == src.length()) {
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());

    System.out.println(name);

    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ name));
    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
        out.write(b);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Source : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/html/download-images-from-a-website-using-jsoup/

Comment: It said "Cannot Resolve Symbol" for the "folderPath" variable, so I made it a local String variable with a path to my desktop. This fixed the initial error message, but then I get the "File Not Found Exception" error. Is that not what I am supposed to put for the folder path? 

Code: https://pastebin.com/w8vV0pCP

Comment: For file not found exception, FileOutputStream throws this error if file doesn't exist or it can't be created. To be sure you probably should first test that the file exists before you create the FileOutputStream (and create with createNewFile() if it doesn't)

`File yourFile = new File("score.txt");
if(!yourFile.exists()) {
    yourFile.createNewFile();
} 
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, false); `

[link] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29